# VS Code PowerShell keeps opening cmdlet external help unexpectedly

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I'm having a very weird problem in VS Code. When writing PowerShell, very often in the middle of typing a cmdlet name, VS Code will open the cmdlet's help page in my browser, stealing focus from VS Code and putting it in my browser. This also often occurs when I hover my mouse over a cmdlet (without clicking any buttons).

Things I've tried:

- Resetting all custom key bindings and settings. The problem still occurs, so I don't think those are at fault.
- Disabling all extensions. This fixes the problem, but then of course I lose out on intellisense and whatnot since the PowerShell extension is disabled.
- Disabling all extensions except for the PowerShell extension. The problem then occurs again.
- Installing the PowerShell Preview extension and disabling all extensions except for it. The problem still occurs.
- Spinning up a new Windows Sandbox and installing VS Code in there, and then turning on VS Code Settings Sync and having it pull down all of my same extensions, settings, key bindings, etc. Cannot reproduce the problem in Windows Sandbox.
- Uninstall and reinstall VS Code. The problem still occurs.

I have a feeling that the issue is somehow tied to the PowerShell intellisense, since the help window typically opens when the intellisense / tooltip window would normally appear. Also, the issue does not happen *every* time I type a cmdlet or hover the mouse over a function, but pretty close; probably around 30% of the time, which makes me think there may be some kind or race condition or something involved as well.

Here's a gif of the problem in action. Note the only keys I type on the keyboard are `Test` and I never click the mouse when hovering over the Get-ChildItem cmdlet.

[image]

I've been having the issue for about a month now, and I don't recall it being tied to a particular version update or anything. I'm using VS Code 1.51.1 on Windows 10 with the PowerShell extension v2020.6.0.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit:** I've also logged this as a GitHub issue with [the VS Code PowerShell extension here](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/3071).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured the issue out myself. Following the advice of [this tweet](https://twitter.com/TobiasPSP/status/1300323729554247681?s=20) I updated my PowerShell Profile to include `$PSDefaultParameterValues.Add("Get-Help:Online", $true)`. It looks like the PowerShell extension calls the `Get-Help` cmdlet in order to populate intellisense and tooltips. This was resulting in the intellisense and tooltips launching the help in an external browser window. The solution was to remove the line from my PowerShell Profile.

I tracked down the repo where the bug is actually occurring and reported [the issue there](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShellEditorServices/issues/1393), and opened a pull request to fix it, so it should be fixed in future versions of VS Code once they take the change :)